# How can I trigger Html.BeginForm by clicking a button?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Here is my `Html.BeginForm` code. I want to pass 2 values to the Action `CheckOutProduct`.
How can I trigger `Html.BeginForm` by clicking a button?

```
@Html.BeginForm("CheckOutProduct", "CheckOut")
{
    <input type="hidden" id="productCodeForCheckout" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" id="productQtyForCheckout" value="0" />
}

<button class="btn" id="checkout"><span>add to cart</span></button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just place a submit button *inside* your form

```
@Html.BeginForm("CheckOutProduct", "CheckOut")
{
    <input type="hidden" id="productCodeForCheckout" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" id="productQtyForCheckout" value="0" />

    <input type="submit" class="btn" id="checkout" title="Add to Cart" />
}
```

If you prefer to stick to `button` instead of `input`, just set the type to `submit`

```
<button type="submit" class="btn" id="checkout">...</button>
```

Comment: now i see `System.Web.Mvc.Html.MvcForm { }` around my button. Do you know why?

Comment: how do i add a confirm alert before delete to this

Answer (score 2):

You should add a `submit` button to the form

```
@Html.BeginForm("CheckOutProduct", "CheckOut")
{
 <input type="hidden" id="productCodeForCheckout" value="" />
 <input type="hidden" id="productQtyForCheckout" value="0" />
 <input type="submit">Add to cart</button>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add FormMethod.Post, a HTTP method for processing the form, either in a form of GET or POST, which in your case is POST method. This will make sure that your method in your controller will fire after Post:

```
@Html.BeginForm("CheckOutProduct", "CheckOut", FormMethod.Post)
{
  <input type="hidden" id="productCodeForCheckout" value="" />
  <input type="hidden" id="productQtyForCheckout" value="0" />

  <input type="submit" class="btn" id="checkout" title="Add to Cart" />
}
```

Comment: The default is `FormMethod.Post` so adding that parameter is not required.